# using LSTM to forecast specific time series

Tags: keras, prediction, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

i have a very specific problem:

i have 2 tables: **configurations** and **selections**

- **configurations:** contains weekly entries for around 300 columns
- **selections:** contains more or less the same weekly entries but in a way lower amount per column

Example for the tables:

> Week | a | b | c | d | ...
>
> week1 | 340 | 650 | 740 | 570 | ...
>
> week2 | 320 | 450 | 700 | 500 | ...
>
> week3 | ...

**What i want to do is:**

1. Train the LSTM based on the configurations
2. structure of the neural net: 300 input neurons, X Hidden layer neurons, 300 output neurons

   - my input neurons "are" the configuration values
   - my output neurons "are" the selection values

**goal**: predict the future selections based on configurations

Is this setting possible to be implemented with keras - LSTM?

I appreciate your help :)

Comment: definitely possible though SO is not the right place for your question : it is not a programming issue you're having, try Cross Validated instead

Comment: @ted thank you for the hint. i am pretty new here in this forum that's why i posted it in the wrong one...